# need code for counting from string

Tags: jquery, counter

i want after i have been type `123A0001-123A0100` the result is `100`.
Or if `123A0123-123A0200` the result is `78`. 
how do i do that?please help.

thanks before.

Comment: no.i want if start from 1 code can read 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = 'A0001-A0100',
    match = str.match(/\d+/g);

if (match) {
    alert(+match[1] - +match[0]);
}
```

`+` (unary plus) will cast the string to a number (does the same as `Number(...)`).

Comment: how if var str= '123x0001-123x0023'?

Comment: @klox, in that case you'd want to change `str.match(/\d+/g)` to `str.match(/\d+(?=-|$)/g)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a calculation plug-in for jQuery.

[Calculation plugin](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/calculation/calculation.plugin.htm)